# Kivy: how to display a list of Objects in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

When I create a class in need to make objects to use the class.
I made a list which gets a new Object every time I touch the screen.
But I don't know how to display these Objects on the kivy side.

Here is my python code:

```
class Cow(Widget):
   pass


class Farm (Widget):       

   cow_flock = ListProperty([])
     
   def on_touch_down (self, touch):
       self.cow_flock.append(Cow())
```

Here is my kivy code:

```
<Cow>:    
    size: 70, 70  
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos:  self.pos

<House>:
    self.cow_flock #this should display the cows
```

I an error:

```
  kivy.lang.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 12:
  ...
       10:
       11:<House>:
  >>   12:    self.doorlist
       13:
       14:
  ...
  Invalid property name
```

I am new in Kivy and I don't know exactly how it works.
To say it in other words; I have no idea which syntax I have to use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create widgets dynamically, you have to add them to a parent (usually a `Layout`) with the parent's `add_widget` method.

Let's assume that your `Farm` class is some kind of `Layout` (and for this, `FloatLayout` or `RelativeLayout` might be best).
You can add an event handler monitoring changes of the `cow_flock` property:

```
class Farm(RelativeLayout):
    cow_flock = ListProperty()
    def on_cow_flock(self, cow_flock):
        self.clear_widgets()
        for cow in cow_flock:
            self.add_widget(cow)
```

This clears all child widgets of the `Farm` instance and adds each cow, one by one, back. Note that `on_cow_flock` is only fired when the list changes (i.e. items are appended or deleted), not when list items change.

BTW, I also assume `House` and `Farm` mean the same thing in your code snippets.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to see. Thank you werry much! You helped me a lot